# How to run a task when variable is undefined in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am looking for a way to perform a task when Ansible variable is not registers or undefined.

E.g.:

```yaml
- name: some task
   command:  sed -n '5p' "{{app.dirs.includes}}/BUILD.info" | awk '{print  $2}'
   when: (! deployed_revision) AND ( !deployed_revision.stdout )
   register: deployed_revision
```

Answer (score 292, accepted):

From the [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-variables):

> If a required variable has not been set, you can skip or fail using Jinja2’s defined test. For example:
>
> ```yaml
> tasks:
>     - name: Run the command if "foo" is defined
>       ansible.builtin.shell: echo "I've got '{{ foo }}' and am not afraid to use it!"
>       when: foo is defined
>
>     - name: Fail if "bar" is undefined
>       ansible.builtin.fail: msg="Bailing out. This play requires 'bar'"
>       when: bar is undefined
> ```

So, in your case, `when: deployed_revision is not defined` should work.

Comment: thanks this worked for me `when: deployed_revision is not defined or deployed_revision.stdout is not defined or deployed_revision.stdout == '' `

Comment: You can also combine it with different conditions: `when: item.sudo is defined and item.sudo == true`

Comment: Don't do what I did and put curly brackets around the foo in `when: foo is defined` (eg this doesn't work: `when: {{ foo }} is defined`

Comment: @David I faced the same issue as you. putting curly braces in when breaks the conditional. To get this working you need to add parenthesis around the conditional. e.g  `when: ({{ foo }} in undefined) `

Comment: The usage of curly braces for conditionals in Ansible is deprecated. Also, no Ansible statement can start with variable expansion (like `{{ foo }}`). This is not because of Ansible, but Yaml would interpret this as an object. If you need to start with a variable expansion, simply surround the whole thing with double quotes (like `"{{ foo }}"`), to force Yaml to see it as a string and pass it as-is to Ansible.

Comment: Awsome. This helped me. +1 for @czerasz for helping with the multiple condition part. I will try this out.

Answer (score 26):

As per latest Ansible Version 2.5, to check if a variable is defined and depending upon this if you want to run any task, use `undefined` keyword.

```
tasks:
    - shell: echo "I've got '{{ foo }}' and am not afraid to use it!"
      when: foo is defined

    - fail: msg="Bailing out. this play requires 'bar'"
      when: bar is undefined
```

[Ansible Documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement)

Answer (score 11):

Strictly stated you must check all of the following: defined, not empty AND not None.

For "normal" variables it makes a difference if defined and set or not set. See `foo` and `bar` in the example below. Both are defined but only `foo` is set.

On the other side registered variables are set to the result of the running command and vary from module to module. They are mostly json structures. You probably must check the subelement you're interested in. See `xyz` and `xyz.msg` in the example below:

```bash
cat > test.yml <<EOF
- hosts: 127.0.0.1

  vars:
    foo: ""          # foo is defined and foo == '' and foo != None
    bar:             # bar is defined and bar != '' and bar == None

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg : ""
    register: xyz    # xyz is defined and xyz != '' and xyz != None
                     # xyz.msg is defined and xyz.msg == '' and xyz.msg != None

  - debug:
      msg: "foo is defined and foo == '' and foo != None"
    when: foo is defined and foo == '' and foo != None

  - debug:
      msg: "bar is defined and bar != '' and bar == None"
    when: bar is defined and bar != '' and bar == None

  - debug:
      msg: "xyz is defined and xyz != '' and xyz != None"
    when: xyz is defined and xyz != '' and xyz != None
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ xyz }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "xyz.msg is defined and xyz.msg == '' and xyz.msg != None"
    when: xyz.msg is defined and xyz.msg == '' and xyz.msg != None
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ xyz.msg }}"
EOF
ansible-playbook -v test.yml
```

Answer (score -3):

You can check if ansible variable is empty or not using this code.

```
tasks:

- fail: msg="The variable 'bar' is empty"
  when: bar|length == 0

- shell: echo "The variable 'foo' is not empty: '{{ foo }}'"
  when: foo|length > 0
```

I hope it is helpful for you.