# How to easily skip ansible tasks when a registered variable was not defined?

Tags: ansible

At some point I do have a `register: varname` in ansible and later I want to perform some tasks only if the `varname.stdout` is defined and not empty.

How can I easily do this in a way that would avoid the infamous:

```
   "One or more undefined variables:
   'dict' object has no attribute 'stdout'"
```

I tried `when: varname is defined and hasattr(varname, 'stdout')` but it seems not to bypass the task and I still get the same error.

Comment: `when: res.stdout is defined` works for me with ansible 2.1.0.0. Don't throw errors when `res` or `res.stdout` are undefined.

Answer (score 2):

(See also [How to run a task when variable is undefined in ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119973/how-to-run-a-task-when-variable-is-undefined-in-ansible/30120360#30120360))

If you want to be super-explicit, something like
`when: varname is defined and varname.stdout is defined and varname.stdout != ''` should work for your purposes.

Comment: Indeed, this should be part of the poster that advertise the simplicity of Ansible! ;)