# Skip Ansible task when variable not defined

Tags: ansible

I have the following task in a playbook:

```
- name: task xyz  
  copy:  
    src="{{ item }}"  
    dest="/tmp/{{ item }}"  
  with_items: "{{ y.z }}"  
  when: y.z is defined
```

`y.z` is not defined, so I'm expecting the task to be skipped. Instead, I receive:

```
FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'z'"
```

I have found:
[How to run a task when variable is undefined in ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119973/how-to-run-a-task-when-variable-is-undefined-in-ansible)
but it seems I implemented just that. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know if the lack of an existing attribute `z` in the `y` dict is the same as `y.z` being undefined. Undefined does not necessarily mean the same thing as, say, null, empty, nil, false, etc.

Comment: as a different way to check, you could try `'z' not in y` (i know that does not answer yout question but it could keep you going.

Comment: Do you mean to try `'z' in y`? In any case, I tried both, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that `with_items` is evaluated before `when`. Actually in real scenarios you put `item` in the `when` conditional. See: [Loops and Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#loops-and-conditionals).

This task will work for you:

```
- name: task xyz
  copy:  
    src: "{{ item }}"  
    dest: "/tmp/{{ item }}"  
  with_items: "{{ (y|default([])).z | default([]) }}"
```

Comment: Referring to the documentation for completeness: "Combining when with with_items (see Loops), be aware that the when statement is processed separately for each item." (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your comment. I included a direct link to the statement you cited in my answer.

Comment: Ah, somehow missed it. You're correct, your answer was already as complete as can be.