# How to run Ansible task only when item in complex JSON is defined?

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have two hosts:

- `foo`
- `bla`

`foo` has no `host_vars`. `bla` has a `host_vars` file with this content:

```
---
# host_vars/bla
'a': {
  'b': {
    'c': 'string'
  }
}
```

my task should only run when the complex JSON exists and contains the item `b`. My logic would be: when `a` exists and has item `b` then it has also `c`.

My task looks like:

```
---
- name: example task
  file:
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    owner: "{{ item.owner }}"
    state: directory
  with_items:
    - { dest: "/tmp/{{ a['b']['c'] }}", owner: root }
  when: a['b'] is defined
```

## result

this task succeeds for `bla` (cause it has the correct JSON) but fails for `foo` which misses the JSON.

```
fatal: [foo]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'b'"}
ok: [bla] => (item={u'dest': u'/tmp/string', u'owner': u'root'})
```

## expected

```
skipping: [foo]: => (item={u'dest': u'/tmp/', u'owner': u'root'})
ok: [bla] => (item={u'dest': u'/tmp/string', u'owner': u'root'})
```

## notice

Now I know that the when statement is interpreted for each item therefore it will not work. Could someone provide a solution that works?

Ansible version is 2.2.0

## edit

```
---
- name: example task
  file:
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    owner: "{{ item.owner }}"
    state: directory
  with_items:
    - { dest: "/tmp/{{ a['b']['c'] | default([]) }}", owner: root }
  when: a['b'] is defined
```

this will not work because `when` is evaluated after `with_items` and as long as `a['b']` is not defined it will fail.

```
fatal: [foo]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'b'"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip Ansible task when variable not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424899/skip-ansible-task-when-variable-not-defined)

Comment: probably yes. but this question doesn't answer my problem it is only pointing it out.

Comment: It is giving the exact solution you need to apply to get away with your problem. Just like the answer I posted below.

Comment: it points out the problem but does not solve it. you wrote it in your answer it will fail as long as the parent item is not defined. I am looking for a solution which will *not* fail when the parent (in this case `a['b']`) is not defined. The way how `default()` works is totally crap IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found something that works:

```
- name: example task
  file:
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    owner: "{{ item.owner }}"
    state: directory
  with_items:
    - { dest: "/tmp/{{ (a['b'] | default({}))['c'] | default('nA') }}", owner: root }
  when: a['b'] is defined
```