# How to Make Ansible variable mandatory

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for the way how to make Ansible to analyze playbooks for required and mandatory variables before run playbook's execution like:

```
- name: create remote app directory hierarchy
  file:
    path: "/opt/{{ app_name | required }}/"
    state: directory
    owner: "{{ app_user | required }}"
    group: "{{ app_user_group | required }}"
  ...
```

and rise error message if variable is undefined, like:

```
please set "app_name" variable before run (file XXX/main.yml:99)
```

Comment: You might find this answer uselful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30120360/4503915

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defining-mandatory-values):

```
{{ variable | mandatory }}
```

Comment: This will not check that the variable is defined _before_ playbook execution as asked in the original question, instead it will fail when the var is evaluated at templating/runtime (which is the default behavior unless you set ` DEFAULT_UNDEFINED_VAR_BEHAVIOR = False`). https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defining-mandatory-values

Comment: It's not a good solution and causes to false positives when the `variable` has value, but its value is `false`. In this situation, ansible wrongly errors that the variable is not set. So, the solution provided by Alexy Vazhnov down there is correct and should be accepted.

Answer (score 57):

As [Arbab Nazar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4391551/arbab-nazar) mentioned, you can use `{{ variable | mandatory }}` (see [Forcing variables to be defined](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-variables-to-be-defined)) inside Ansible task.

But I think it looks nicer to add this as first task, it checks is `app_name`, `app_user` and `app_user_group` exist:

```
- name: 'Check mandatory variables are defined'
  assert:
    that:
      - app_name is defined
      - app_user is defined
      - app_user_group is defined
```

Comment: Here is better version from @Lev: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61563967/10354853

Comment: Thanks, but your solution is easier to remember and use.

Answer (score 19):

Usually inside a role I perform checking input variables like in the example:

```yaml
- name: "Verify that required string variables are defined"
  ansible.builtin.assert:
    that: 
      - ahs_var is defined
      - ahs_var | length > 0
      - ahs_var != None
    fail_msg: "{{ ahs_var }} needs to be set for the role to work"
    success_msg: "Required variable {{ ahs_var }} is defined"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: ahs_var
  with_items:
    - ahs_item1
    - ahs_item2
    - ahs_item3
```

by the way there are some tricks:

1. Don't use global variables inside a role.
2. If you want use global variables define the role specific variable & set global variable to it i.e. `some_role_name__db_port: "{{ db_port | default(5432) }}"`.
3. It makes sense to use role name as the prefix for variable. it helps to understand the source inventory easier.
4. Your role might be looped some how, so it makes sense to override the default `item`.

Comment: I like your double underscore to delimit the role name within the variable name. I have used this convention with success in other applications.

Answer (score 14):

One way to check if mandatory variables are defined is:

```
- fail:
    msg: "Variable '{{ item }}' is not defined"
  when: item not in vars
  with_items:
    - app_nam
    - var2
```

Comment: in my case, I had to replace `with_item` to `with_list`. Beside that, I changed the condition `item not in vars` to `lookup('vars', item) == ''` because I defined those variables inside role's `defaults/main.yml` and I set the default value as an empty string

Answer (score 6):

If using a [role-based](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure) architecture, check out the docs on [role argument validation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-argument-validation).

It allows for you to specify a `roles/<role_name>/meta/argument_specs.yml` file which allows you to make variables required. Here is an example taken from their [sample specification](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#sample-specification):

```
# roles/myapp/meta/argument_specs.yml
---
argument_specs:
  # roles/myapp/tasks/main.yml entry point
  main:
    short_description: The main entry point for the myapp role.
    options:
      myapp_int:
        type: "int"
        required: false
        default: 42
        description: "The integer value, defaulting to 42."

      myapp_str:
        type: "str"
        required: true
        description: "The string value"

  # roles/myapp/tasks/alternate.yml entry point
  alternate:
    short_description: The alternate entry point for the myapp role.
    options:
      myapp_int:
        type: "int"
        required: false
        default: 1024
        description: "The integer value, defaulting to 1024."
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 approaches:

1. Specify `|mandatory` filter

   1. Beware dictionaries - if a key with mandatory value fails to eval, you may have a hard time uh understanding which is it.
2. Use `assert` module