# ansible: correct way to check a list of variables has been set?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to use `when: item is undefined` in Ansible 2.5 to check if a list of variables have been set, as below:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: validate some variables
      fail:
        msg: "Required variable {{item}} has not been provided"
      when: item is undefined
      loop:
        - v1
        - v2
```

However, this never fails regardless of whether `v1` or `v2` are provided.

Switching the `when` to use jinja2 templating works:

```
when: "{{item}} is undefined"
```

But ansible complains about this:

> [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{item}} is
>   undefined

What is the correct way loop through a list of variable names and checked they have been set?

Comment: Unfortunately that the way it works. I do the same way:

---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    required_variables:
    - cloud_yy
    - cloud_xx

  tasks:
    - name: Validate required variables
      fail:
        msg: "No value specified for '{{ item }}'"
      when: ({{ item }} is undefined) or ({{ item }} is defined and {{ item|trim == '' }})
      with_items: "{{ required_variables }}"

Comment: Your are using `v1` and `v2` as strings.. if you will use 
```- "{{ v1 }}"
 - "{{ v2 }}" ```you'll get another error saying you can't use undefined variables in loops..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Make Ansible variable mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013306/how-to-make-ansible-variable-mandatory)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the `vars` structure:

```
- name: validate some variables
  fail:
    msg: "Required variable {{item}} has not been provided"
  when: vars[item] is undefined
  loop:
    - v1
    - v2
```

Or, in Ansible 2.5, with the new `vars` lookup plugin:

```
- name: validate some variables
  debug:
  when: lookup('vars', item) is undefined
  loop:
    - v1
    - v2
```

Although not with the error message you specified, but a default error message for a lookup plugin.

<sup>The module won't even be executed, so you can use whatever ー I replaced `fail` with `debug` in the example above.</sup>

Comment: Cool one! Didn’t know about the vars lookup plugin in 2.5. Thanks techraf (+1)

Comment: Wouldn't `assert` be a more appropriate module?

Comment: Not sure if this changed, but in 2.7, the `vars` lookup will _result in an error if any of the variables is undefined_ (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/vars.html).  The first example seems to work though...

Answer (score 6):

Inside loop, you can use `{{ variable | mandatory }}` (see [Forcing variables to be defined](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-variables-to-be-defined))

I think it looks nicer to add this as first task, it checks is v1 and v2 exist:

```
- name: 'Check mandatory variables are defined'
  assert:
    that:
      - v1 is defined
      - v2 is defined
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using below

```
  with_items:
    - v1
    - v2
```