# Ansible : how to exit from a playbook and forcing error?

Tags: ansible

I'm setting an internal variable from an extra variable :

```
- name : define my internal var
  set_fact:
    internal_var: "{{ 'blue' if my_extravar == 'sky' else 'red' if my_extravar = 'fire' else 'unknown' }}"
```

I would like to stop my playbook with this error message :

```
ERROR internal_var is 'unknown', please set a correct value to my_extravar
```

Comment: Use an assertion: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html

Comment: Or use a fail with an adapted condition, like suggested in the answer to this question: [How to run a task when variable is undefined in ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119973/how-to-run-a-task-when-variable-is-undefined-in-ansible)